# The papers refereed in the article is not showing numbers and at the end the list of reference is not generated

Tags: citing

I have a small code wherein I am trying to write an article with some references in it, my article is coming nice but the references are not appearing in the generated PDF. How to overcome this.

```
\documentclass[Review,sagev,times,doublespace]{sagej}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{moreverb,url}

% math releated packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lineno}

% figure releated packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}


%table
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
% refrence and bibolography
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\def\volumeyear{2019}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum  \cite{kukla1991green}
\bibliographystyle{SageH}
 %\bibliographystyle{SageV}
 \bibliography{refs_conf_1.bib}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: This may not be the root problem here, but still: The correct syntax for `\bibliography{<filename of bib file>}` is to give `<filename of bib file>` **without the `.bib`** extension. Some systems accept the incorrect input `\bibliography{refs_conf_1.bib}` and will attempt to find the correct `.bib` file (`refs_conf_1.bib`) but some systems are less benevolent and will try to look for `refs_conf_1.bib.bib`. **The correct input is `\bibliography{refs_conf_1}`.**

Comment: Have you run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX on your document? The references will only appear if you successfully run BibTeX after a complete LaTeX run that did not error. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for more details and a great explanation.

Comment: now the refrences are coming but they are not coming in acending order, the first cited paper is showing the no 16 in the refrence.

Comment: Is the bibliography style file `sageH.bst` available online somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I think an example  file is provide in sage official site

Comment: But last time used the same tex file in over leaf the references appeared in proper order

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` lists references in the order in which they appear in the document.  I don't know the style `SageH` or `SageV`, but since the order is defined by the `\bibliographystyle`, you should investigate what options are provided by the Sage support.